# Cannot create the SqlConnection Object in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm writing a simple program to access one local database, yet it says: the type or namespace name sqlconnect could not be found

error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

anyone have an idea about that? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQL_Server_Connect_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("integrated security=SSPI;data source=Bo_Test_Database; persist security info=False; initial catalog=T_User"))
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=Bob_Test_Database; User ID=sa; Password=t123456");
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

            }
            Console.WriteLine("hehe");
        }

    }
}
```

- I enabled the sa account and the password is valid
- the database is on local
- db name = Bob_Test_Database, the table's name is dbo.T_User

Comment: I don't see any `sqlconnect` in your code

Comment: Please don't paraphrase error messages.  Quote them verbatim.

Comment: Why do you have integrated security=.; ?? Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.

Comment: And moreoever, there is no server in the connexion string

Comment: If you put the connection string in the application settings, not only you will be able to make your application configurable, but you will benefits the Visual Studio wizard to create the connection string. Read more on [How to: Save and Edit Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx)

Comment: Hey guys, just ask did you see any wrong syntax I wrote in the connecting string?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your connection string using a [udl file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140076%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

After you get the udl file to sucessfully connect to the DB, simply open it using notepad and copy the connection text to your application.

Comment: +1 for the `.udl` file trick. Very useful. But be a bit careful, use the UDL to create the cx string easily, but try to understand the meaning of the parameters because all platforms won't have the same string.

Comment: the sqlconnect is in using() part, to take big advantage of connection resources

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any **sqlconnect** in your code.  Anyway, try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=T_User;
                                       Initial Catalog=Bob_Test_Database;
                                       Persist Security Info=True;")
```